# Дефис и прописная в прилагательных от географических названий?

Tags: орфография

Почему Центрально-Азиатский регион, Северо-Американская котловина, но Центральноафриканская Республика?

Американо-Российский университет или Американо-российский университет?

Answer (score 2):

По правилам все через дефис, и я такое написание тоже встречала, вот, например:

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/194381/%D1%

Но в большинстве изданий Центральноафриканская Республика пишется слитно, видимо, по традиции, вполне возможно, что  ориентировались  на французское название: Republique Centrafricaine

Сравните англ.: Южно-Африканская Республика - Republic of South Africa

Американо-российский университет, как Американо-российский бизнес институт (АРБИ) при МНЭПУ. В названии университета первое слово с большой буквы, остальные со строчной.

Answer (score 1):

Причину расхождения со способами образования составных географических названий внутри русского языка (они могут иметь условный, терминологический характер и сильно отличаться от всех иностранных) здесь можно усмотреть в факте переноса имени собственного из конкретного языка. Для каждого исходного языка в паре с русским действуют свои правила практической транскрипции (переноса в письменную форму), направленные на однозначность и возможность обратного отыскания. Помимо фонетической транскрипции, применяются приёмы транслитерации (по необходимости) и изредка - прямого перевода, как в этом случае. При переводе иногда возможно сохранить деление на слова и связь между ними. В случае Южно-Африканской Республики название, составленное внутри русского языка, совпадает с переведённым (the Republic of South Africa), поскольку предлог 'of' придаёт двум другим словам оттенок (составного) прилагательного (Prince of Wales, sea of green, sky of blue), а дефис при таком переводе позволяет сохранить исходное деление на слова. В случае Центральноафриканской Республики перевод сделан не с английского, а с французского (République centrafricaine), где прилагательное пишется в одно слово, и такое в русском языке есть - для других случаев (напр. центральноафриканские виды флоры и фауны), поэтому перевод возможно было сделать в одно слово - как в исходном названии. Это особый приём перевода - в интересах сближения имени собственного с исходным названием (ценой расхождения с русским географическим термином). Для сравнения, географические понятия, образуемые внутри языка от слов "Центральная Африка" (Центрально-Африканский щит и пр.) пишутся в соответствии с русскими правилами их образования.